# Perl search for string and get the full line from text file

Tags: perl

I want to search for a string and get the full line from a text file through Perl scripting.

So the text file will be like the following.

```
data-key-1,col-1.1,col-1.2
data-key-2,col-2.1,col-2.2
data-key-3,col-3.1,col-3.2
```

Here I want to apply `data-key-1` as the search string and get the full line into a Perl variable.

Here I want the exact replacement of `grep "data-key-1" data.csv` in the shell.

Some syntax like the following worked while running in the console.

```
perl -wln -e 'print if /\bAPPLE\b/' your_file
```

But how can I place it in a script? With the `perl` keyword we can't put it into a script. Is there a way to avoid the loops?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you'd know the command line options you are giving for your one-liner, you'd know exactly what to write inside your `perl` script. When you read a file, you need a loop. Choice of loop can yield different results performance wise. Using `for` loop to read a while is more expensive than using a `while` loop to read a file.

Your one-liner:

```
perl -wln -e 'print if /\bAPPLE\b/' your_file
```

is basically saying:

- `-w` : Use warnings
- `-l` : Chomp the newline character from each line before processing and place it back during printing.
- `-n` : Create an implicit `while(<>) { ... }` loop to perform an action on each line
- `-e` : Tell `perl` interpreter to execute the code that follows it.
- `print if /\bAPPLE\b/` to print entire line if line contains the word `APPLE`.

So to use the above inside a `perl` script, you'd do:

```
#!usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<', 'your_file' or die "Cannot open file: $!\n";

while(<$fh>) {
    my $line = $_ if /\bAPPLE\b/;
    # do something with $line
}
```

`chomp` is not really required here because you are not doing anything with the line other then checking for an existence of a word.

Comment: Thank you Jaypal. This explanation is clear. And I was not realize that `-n` doing a loop. Can you help me to assign this value to a variable instead of printing.

Comment: Simply i want to get the line extracted with the search keyword to go to a variable like `$line`. For example if i search for the string `data-key-2` in that file. The line `data-key-2,col-2.1,col-2.2` should go to a perl variable $line as string. Then i can process that string for my program.

Answer (score 3):

```
open($file, "<filename");
while(<$file>) {
   print $_ if ($_ =~ /^data-key-3,/);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. and this i'm already using. But if you can suggest without loop it would be great. because loop is highly consuming the resource.

Comment: It's impossible w/o a loop. Even if you code it as a perl one-liner it's still a loop...

Comment: But syntax like follows working `perl -wln -e 'print if /\bAPPLE\b/' your_file` in console. Is there any way to convert it to place inside the script?

Comment: IF you know the key only occurrs once, you can exit the loop after finding it.

Comment: `perl -wln -e 'print if /\bAPPLE\b/' your_file` also performs a loop internally. There is no difference to this code.

Comment: if you can suggest me a way to convert this syntax to be usable inside a perl script and assign the value to a variable it would be helpful.

Comment: Tried `perl -wln -e 'print if /^data-key-3,/' your_file`?

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# the file name of your .csv file
my $file = 'data.csv';


# open the file for reading
open(FILE, "<$file") or
 die("Could not open log file. $!\n");

 #process line by line:
while(<FILE>) {

 my($line) = $_;

 # remove any trail space (the newline)
 # not necessary, but again, good habit
 chomp($line);


my @result = grep (/data-key-1/, $line);
push (@final, @result); 
}
print @final;
```

Comment: This will work but is it possible to get the variable `$line` without loop by using another way?

Comment: Strange choice to use `grep` instead of a simple `if`. Also, `@result` will hold only the *last* line that contains the string.

Comment: @Borodin It's an option but I agree if is better as shown above. :)

I added push :)

Comment: @Borodin: Can you give me an idea how to convert this command if i'm using inside a perl script `perl -wln -e 'print if /\bAPPLE\b/' your_file` as you suggest this syntax have if and it is one line solution. I need this syntax goes inside perl script and the value to assign to a variable.